# Does ClassName::method() mean that method(), a member function of ClassName, is called?

Tags: c++

I'm reading sample code from an SDK, and I see this:

```
PXCSenseManager *senseManager = PXCSenseManager::CreateInstance();
```

Does this mean that CreateInstance() is a method in the PXCSenseManager class and that it is called?

Comment: Yes. Probably `CreateInstance` is a `static`methode.

Comment: @Gernot1976 Thanks. It appears that you are correct. Here is the documentation for PXCSenseManager::CreateInstance(): https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?createinstance_pxcsensemanager.html

Answer (score 3):

Yup, `CreateInstance()` is a `public` `static` member function of class `PXCSenseManager`.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the `CreateInstance` function in the namespace `PXCSenseManager` is being called. From the beginning of that line one can see that PXCSenseManager is actually some class. The nature of a function that creates instances and the way it is called with an explicit namespace makes it extremely likely that `CreateInstance` is a static member function of the `PXCSenseManager` class, but if this line of code comes from within a non-static member function there is a theoretical possible that `CreateInstance` is a non-static member function.